# Running Parallel Activities in AWS SWF

Tags: amazon-swf

I am writing a AWS SWF workflow, in which the first activities evaluates the number of partitions and it is passed to child workflow. The child workflow in decider loops over the partition returned by first activity and start the max. allowed activities in parallel. Suppose if max. allowed value is 50, at a time 50 activities are started in parallel. But, the issue we face that next 50 is not started till all 50 completes i.e. it stalls all other partitions till all 50 completes. The execution happens in 50 batch. Below is the code example:

```
@Override
public void execute(@Nonnull final Execution execution, @Nonnull final Step step)
        throws ExecutionException {
    Promise<Queue<Step>> stepQueuePromise = activitiesClient.partition(step, context);
    Promise<Void> exitCode = executeSteps(stepQueuePromise, execution, context);
    activitiesClient.verify(step, exitCode);
}

@Asynchronous
private Promise<Void> executeStepsInBatches(@Nonnull final Queue<Step> stepQueue,
                                   @Wait final List<Promise<Void>> previousSteps,
                                   @Nonnull final Execution execution,
                                   @Nonnull final Context context) {

    List<Promise<Void>> stepListPromises = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < concurrentStepThreshold && !stepQueue.isEmpty(); i++) {
        Promise<Void> stepPromise = activitiesClient.execute(execution, stepQueue.poll(), context);
        stepListPromises.add(stepPromise);
    }

    if (!stepListPromises.isEmpty()) {
        return executeStepsInBatches(stepQueue, stepListPromises, execution, context);
    } else {
        return Promise.Void();
    }
}
```

We want to execute 50 activities in batch but as soon as the few completes, the new activities should be submitted to match the 50 parallel running count. Can someone suggest how can we achieve this?

EDIT (NEW CODE)

I tried below code:

```
@Override
public void execute(@Nonnull final Execution execution, @Nonnull final Step step)
        throws ExecutionException {

    Promise<Queue<Step>> stepQueuePromise = activitiesClient.partition(step, context);
    executeSteps(stepQueuePromise, execution, context);
}

@Asynchronous
private void executeSteps(@Nonnull final Promise<Queue<Step>> stepQueuePromise,
                          @Nonnull final Execution execution,
                          @Nonnull final Context context) {
    Integer numNotReady = 0;
    List<Promise<Void>> currentPromises = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator<Step> inputItr = stepQueuePromise.get().iterator();
    while (inputItr.hasNext() && numNotReady < 20) {
        Promise<Void> promise = activitiesClient.execute(execution, inputItr.next(), context);
        currentPromises.add(promise);

        if (!promise.isReady()) {
            numNotReady++;
        }
    }
    log.info("Num of not ready" + numNotReady);
    waitForPromises(currentPromises);
}

@Asynchronous
void waitForPromises(@Wait final List<Promise<Void>> activityOutputs) {
}
```

The first loop started 20 activities in parallel. But, even though the decider ran the new activties were not submitted. I can see the log which i added to verify that decider ran:
06 Aug 2018 17:16:34,962 [INFO]  (SWF Decider ExecutorTaskList_1.0 1) com.amazon.traffic.cafe.orchestrator.swf.exec.impl.SwfExecutorImpl: Num of not ready20
06 Aug 2018 17:16:50,808 [INFO]  (SWF Decider ExecutorTaskList_1.0 1) com.amazon.traffic.cafe.orchestrator.swf.exec.impl.SwfExecutorImpl: Num of

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What benefit do you hope to get as compared to scheduling all of the activity tasks at once?

Comment: We don't want to run all once because if we do that then it loads the dependent service which is called from the activity get loaded. Hence, we want to cap it to 50 as concurrent runs.

Comment: Can't you just schedule all of them and cap it at 50 workers for that activity then?

Comment: We have a common activity type for all activities. The activities behavior changes based on the parameter passed to it. It is not possible for us to create different activity worker types as we have lot different configuration which can be passed to activity. Hence, looking if we can do something like this else we will take this route only.

Comment: Are you hoping to only run 50 at a time across all workflow executions, or 50 at a time per workflow execution? I assumed it was the former because you're trying to throttle your impact on a downstream system. Is that correct?

Comment: I want to control 50 in a workflow. We have system outside which controls number of running workflows. Hence, currently, we don't have an issue with parallel running workflow. We are working on solution which can control the number of similar running activity from the same system. But, interim i am looking if something of which i am trying to do is feasible or not.

Comment: I think the simplest way to do what you want is to  create 50 parallel child workflows, and assign 1/50th of the tasks to each one. Each child workflow executes only one at a time, but as soon as it is done, it starts on its next assigned task. Similarly, you could try to chain individual activities so that after task X finishes, it unblocks task X+50. Would either of these approaches work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following should work:

```
@Asynchronous
private Promise<Void> executeStepsInBatches(@Nonnull final Queue<Step> stepQueue,
                                   @Wait final List<Promise<Void>> previousSteps,
                                   @Nonnull final Execution execution,
                                   @Nonnull final Context context) {

    List<Promise<Void>> stepListPromises = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < concurrentStepThreshold; i++) {
        Promise<Void> stepPromise = executeNext(stepQueue, execution, context, stepPromise);
        stepListPromises.add(stepPromise);
    }
    return Promises.listOfPromisesToPromise(stepListPromises);
}

@Asynchronous
private Promise<Void> executeNext(Queue<Step> stepQueue, Execution execution, Context context, Promise<?> previous) {
   if (stepQueue.isEmpty()) {
     return Promise.Void();
   }
   Promise<Void> stepPromise = activitiesClient.execute(execution, stepQueue.poll(), context);
   // Loop recursively
   return executeNext(stepQueue, execution, stepPromise);    
}
```

Comment: How cadence solves this problem? Is it similar? It's such a common case but seems it's not quite straightforward to solve it with SWF.

Comment: Cadence does support blocking operations inside a workflow. So the simplest solution would be spawining 50 parallel threads and let each of them execute activities in a loop blocking on an activity completion.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the below code worked and it is tested:

```
@Override
public void execute(@Nonnull final Execution execution, @Nonnull final Step step)
        throws ExecutionException {


    Context context = getContext(execution, step);

    Promise<Queue<Step>> stepQueue = activitiesClient.partition(step, context);

    /**
     * List to hold the promise of started activities.
     */
    Promise<?>[] batchPromises = new Promise<?>[50];

    /**
     * Initialize the list with ready promises.
     */
    Arrays.fill(batchPromises, Promise.Void());

    /**
     * OrPromise list to unblock as soon as one of the activity is completed.
     */
    OrPromise waitForAtleastOneInBatch = new OrPromise(batchPromises);

    Promise<Void> exitCode = startActivityInBatch(execution, context, stepQueue, waitForAtleastOneInBatch);

}

@Asynchronous
private Promise<Void> startActivityInBatch(final Execution execution, final Context context,
                                            final Promise<Queue<Step>> stepQueue,
                                            final OrPromise waitForAtleastOneInBatch) {
    /**
     * Executes only when one of the promise is ready.
     */
    Promise<?>[] existingBatchPromises = waitForAtleastOneInBatch.getValues();

    /**
     * In this loop, we iterate over the promise list and if the promise is ready we replace it with
     * new promise by starting new activity.
     */
    for (int existingBatchIterator = 0; existingBatchIterator < existingBatchPromises.length;
         existingBatchIterator++) {
        /**
         * If the existing promise is ready, call the next task replace the ready promise.
         */
        if (existingBatchPromises[existingBatchIterator].isReady()) {
            final Step step = stepQueue.get().poll();
            if (step == null) {
                /**
                 * This means that queue is empty and we have run all the activities.
                 */
                existingBatchPromises[existingBatchIterator] = Promise.Void();
            } else {
                existingBatchPromises[existingBatchIterator] = activitiesClient.execute(execution, step, context);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * call recursively till  we have messages in queue.
     */
    if (stepQueue.get().size() > 0) {
        return startActivityInBatch(execution, context, stepQueue, new OrPromise(existingBatchPromises));
    } else {
        /**
         * AndPromise is used to make the workflow wait till all Promises are ready.
         */
        return new AndPromise(existingBatchPromises);
    }
}
```